# How to get tree data for self join model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have model which place have many child places as bellow

```
    class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :parent   ,  class_name: "Place", foreign_key: "parent_id"
      has_many  :childs     , class_name: "Place", foreign_key: "parent_id"
    end
```

and i want to get data from this model in bellow form to represent in tree

```
    data = [
     {
       label: 'place',
       children: [
        { label: 'child1' , childern: [ {label: 'child11'} , {label: 'child12'}] },
        { label: 'child2' , childern: [ {label: 'child21'} , {label: 'child22'}] }
       ]
     },
      {
    label: 'place',
    children: [
        { label: 'child3' }
        ]
      }
     ]
```

I started with this function

```
    def get_tree(Place)
      data = []
      Place.all.each do |place|

    dataInner= {label: place.name ,id: place.id}
    children = [] # to hold childern data

    place.childs.each do |child|
      childhash = {label: child.name , id: child.id }
      children.push(childhash)
    end
    dataInner.merge!(children: children) # push childern
    data.push(dataInner)       
  end
 return data
end
```

This function work ok but get depth 1 of childs only.
I want to get tree with any depth of childs

Comment: Be lazy and use ActsAsTree https://github.com/amerine/acts_as_tree

Answer (score 3):

try something like

```
def get_tree(node)
  return {label: node.name} if node.childs.empty?

  {label: node.name, children: node.childs.collect { |v| get_tree(v) }
end
```